# Homomorphisms between $\Bbb Z[S_3] \to \Bbb Z[\Bbb Z \backslash 2 \Bbb Z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, group-rings

Show that there are at most $4$ ring homomorphisms between $\Bbb Z[S_3] \to \Bbb Z[\Bbb Z \backslash 2 \Bbb Z]$.

Here is what I did :

We know that ring homomorphisms send inversible elements to inversible elements. Since $1.(123)$ is inversible then $f(1.(123))$ is inversible in $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z \backslash 2 \Bbb Z]$. Inversible elements in $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z \backslash 2 \Bbb Z]$ are $±1.\overline{0}$ and  $±1.\overline{1}$ so at most $4$ possible images for $1.(123)$ so at most $4$ ring homomorphisms between $\Bbb Z[S_3] \to \Bbb Z[\Bbb Z \backslash 2 \Bbb Z]$.

What should I do next ? I would like to say that when an image for $1.(123)$ is chosen then all others elements are fixed but I struggle a bit.

Comment: Your claim in the last paragraph would be true if $(123)$ generated $S_3$, but that's not the case. You need to consider another element, e.g. $(12)$, too, and consider also the multiplicative order of these elements.

Comment: So I need to eliminate some possibilities for the image of $(123)$ so that it makes at most 4 possibilities with the ones of $(12)$ right ?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it

Comment: By $\mathbb Z\backslash 2\mathbb Z,$ do you mean $\mathbb Z\smallsetminus2\mathbb Z,$ i.e. $\{x\in \mathbb Z : x\notin2\mathbb Z\} \text{?}$ (The latter can also be written as $\mathbb Z\setminus2\mathbb Z,$ which differs typographically from $\mathbb Z\backslash2\mathbb Z.$) $\qquad$